# Is there any way to undo DELETE for a Teradata table?

Tags: teradata

I have a table`Test` .

It was created like this   :

```
CREATE SET TABLE mydbname.Test,FALLBACK ,
     NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
     NO AFTER JOURNAL,
     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
     DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO
     (
      nameid INTEGER)
PRIMARY INDEX ( nameid);
```

---

Is there any way I can restore the data if I delete all rows `DELETE FROM Test`  ?

Is there any way to undo DELETE for a Teradata table?

Comment: Presumably you have backups? If not, then the data's gone. Regardless, offtopic - not a programming question. We are not general server/DB tech support.

Comment: 'fallback' only works for 'drop' ?

Comment: DELETE can only be rolled back if the transaction is not yet committed. FALLBACK only protects from hardware errors (i.e. an AMP looses it's disk) not from stupid users :-)